# Python two dimensional lists

Tags: python, list, python-requests

Please how do I use the .append() method to add a list with values (two dimensional lists) ?

For example if you are asked to Use the .append() method to add a list with the values of "computer science" and an associated grade value of 100 to our two-dimensional list of gradebook

How do you go about it?

Comment: could you please post some code for context. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting a question please **use examples** and **show what you have already tried**.

Comment: Okay please, this is what I did                                                                               new_value = ("computer science", 100)
gradebook.append('new_value')
print(gradebook)

Comment: See my answer below.  Your first line above should have square brackets around it: new_value = ["computer science", 100]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have rectified it but I'm still getting an error which says " AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gradebook = []

class1 = ['computer science', 100]
class2 = ['history of needlework', 90]

gradebook.append(class1)
gradebook.append(class2)

print(gradebook)
```

Comment: Thanks for the responds. Please what if gradebook contains an existing list and you are asked to add a list of values of "computer science"  and its associated value.                  
 For example: gradebook = ['physics', 98], ['calculus', 97], ['poetry', 85], ['history', 88]                which you are ask to add ['computer science', 90]

Comment: That works fine.  Note that the first line above reinitializes the list, so leave that off.  But the best way to learn is to try all this stuff out for yourself.

Comment: Okay, Thank you Rusty

Comment: You're welcome.  Can you mark the answer as accepted?